# VBA: If there exist non-blank cells in Range(X), continue with code. Else, go to end

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I'm trying to put a Try-Catch type line of code into my program in VBA.  What I've got is below.  However, this code just runs to the End If right away, regardless of whether or not there is data in the cells of column A.  What can I do to fix this?
Thank you.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:= _
    "0"
If Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Text = "<>0" _
Then
(other code)
(other code)
(other code)
End If
```

Comment: this code is actually comparing the Text inside the SpecialCells of Range("A:A"), and only if that text equals the string "<>0" your code will execute

Comment: How would you got about doing it instead?  I'm trying something like       `If Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Text = Array("PF", "PH") _
    Then`

Answer (score 1):

To see if a range contains **any** visible data:

```
Sub hfksjdfh()
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, r As Range
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set r = Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    If wf.CountA(r) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "There is at least one visible cell in column A with data"
    Else
        MsgBox "The visible part of column contains no data"
    End If
End Sub
```